# Generate records on interval of time (Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to generate records on given start-date, end-date and time frequency(Weekly, Monthly etc.)

**Example-1:**

1. Start Date: 15 Jan 2011
2. End Date: 31 Dec 2011
3. Frequency: Monthly

**Generated Reports:**

1. 15 Jan - 31 Jan
2. 1 Feb - 28 Feb (29 Feb Leap Year)
3. 1 March - 31 March

.
.
.

- 4- 1 Dec - 31 Dec

**Example-2**

- Start Date: 15 Jan 2011
- End Date: 31 Dec 2011
- Frequency: Weekly

**Generated Reports:**

- 1- 15 Jan - 16 Jan
- 2- 17 Jan - 23 Jan
- 3- 24 Jan - 30 Jan

.
.
.

- 50- 26 Dec - 31 Dec

Same as Quarterly.

Any Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking is basically how to loop through months/weeks/quarters.

This should give you a good start to point you in the right direction I hope.  You just have to muck around with the built in SQL date functions like `DATEADD, DATEDIFF & DATEPART`

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME
DECLARE @TimePeriod NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @RptDate DATETIME

SET @startDate = '1/15/2011'
SET @endDate = '12/31/2011'
SET @TimePeriod = 'Monthly'

SET @RptDate = @startDate
WHILE @RptDate < @endDate
BEGIN
    PRINT @RptDate      --- This prints out the dates I think you want
    IF @TimePeriod = 'Monthly'
        SET @RptDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(@RptDate) + 1,@RptDate))

    IF @TimePeriod = 'Weekly'
        SET @RptDate = DATEADD(ww, 1, DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(weekday,@RptDate) + 1,@RptDate))

    IF @TimePeriod = 'Quarterly'
        SET @RptDate = DATEADD(qq, 1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @RptDate), -1) + 1)

END
```